# how to use require in javascript

Tags: javascript, requirejs, require

I try to use require in JS but I get the following error
`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`
I have to files.
`main.js`:

`const count = 9;
 module.exports = count;`

`index.js:`

`const count = require('./index');
 console.log(count);`

How to use require?

Answer (score 1):

Require is a NodeJS thing. Are you trying this in NodeJS? Or in browser Javascript. I suspect the latter. In that case you have to include your files withing your HTML using
`<script src="./index.js"></script>`
and
`<script src="./main.js"></script>`
instead.
Within NodeJS require should always be possible unless your installation is corrupted in a really weird way.